# in asp.net save text to Database then call it by load page does not work, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

my in program 
First call text from datadase then post it in textbox 
second make a change on the text in textbos 
finally I need the the change in database .
problem when I click on the save button does not make  the change in textbox but only on the database

```
namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class WebForm17 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         DATAACCESS aaa = new DATAACCESS();
         string  Dname = "Finding";

         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              aaa = new DATAACCESS();
              TextBox2.Text= aaa.GetDoctext(Dname, 90);
         }

         protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

             string textboxvalue = Request.Form[TextBox2.UniqueID];
             aaa.savetext(textboxvalue, Dname, 90);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is populate the text box only if the page has not been postback yet:

```
namespace WebApplication4 
{ 
  public partial class WebForm17 : System.Web.UI.Page 
  { 
     DATAACCESS aaa = new DATAACCESS(); 
     string  Dname = "Finding"; 

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     {  
          aaa = new DATAACCESS(); 

          if(!IsPostBack)
          {
              TextBox2.Text= aaa.GetDoctext(Dname, 90); 
          }
     } 

     protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     { 

         string textboxvalue = TextBox2.Text;
         aaa.savetext(textboxvalue, Dname, 90); 
     } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn about the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) - `page_load` will execute *before* any button events.

This means that you are only saving to database *after* you have tried to load from it.